# Does this concrete slab need to replaced or lifted?

Tags: concrete, basement, leak, foundation, waterproofing

House built in late 40s.

Bought 1.5 years ago

Finished basement. Im assuming it was waterproofed?

My backyard has 2 slabs of concrete that are sunk and tilted towards the house by like half an inch. I’m worried a lot of water is going to get in the foundation. Does these need to be replaced, can I get it lifted, or can just I seal the gap with some polyurethane and leave it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you assuming that the basement of a house built in the 1940s was waterproofed, and what does it have to do with the question of repairing/replacing concrete slabs in the back yard?

Answer (score 1):

According to the pictures the slabs look like they are in good shape, just lower than they should be. There are contractors that can pump a type of material under the slab to lift it up hydraulically. The only thing the pictures don't show is a mark on the foundation wall where the slab used to be before it sunk. It doesn't have to be there, It would simply show there is room for the slab to be raised back up.

It is important to get the slab to pitch rain water away from the foundation. Waterproofed or not, it is not a good idea to allow water to concentrate itself along a basement wall.

If you contact a concrete company that does slabs, there is a good chance they will tell you to replace it, because that is what they do. It would be worthwhile getting   a price from them to compare with the company that can lift it. Who knows, replacement may be the cheaper option.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has been that way for a while. If there are no water intrusion issues you're probably good. It would still probably bother me. I would contact a reputable concrete contractor to take a look. It looks like it heaved away from the house so I'm not sure lifting is an option but the contractor would be best able to tell.